# How to redirecting and then rewriting at .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Ok, I'm a newbie... first time asking things here.
I have a domain called **example.com**
All my website is at the following URL: **https://example.com/example.com/inter/pf2/**
What I want is the following:
When a user goes to https://example.com show all the content at https://example.com/example.com/inter/pf2/ but the URL keep saying **example.com**
I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^$ /example.com/inter/pf2/ [L]
```

But it is not working

EDIT:

```
This is the .htaccess:

RewriteEngine on

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

RewriteRule ^/?$ %{HTTP_HOST}/inter/pf2/ [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Do you get any error ? Please be more specific

Comment: 404 error. With 2 .htaccess files gives me that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example\.com/inter/pf2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ %{HTTP_HOST}/inter/pf2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works, but if I type example.com/folder it shows a 404 error. For the files in the root folder ok. And if I type www.example.com it gives me 404 error

Comment: @nanmaniac, please do show your full htaccess file in your question.

Comment: @nanmaniac, ok, is there any folder/directory present in your system like `hostname/inter/pf2/`? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: yes, with the URL you can get to the files this way:  example.com/example.com/inter/pf2/

Comment: @nanmaniac, ok how about keeping your htaccess file inside pf2 directory? That will do the trick I believe, please try it once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: If I copy the .htaccess to that folder , the website has the same behaviour (cache deleted). I've also deleted the .htaccess from root, but then it does not work at all

Comment: I have at public_html  folder the .htaccess file and a folder called example.com. At example.com I have a folder called inter. At inter there is a folder called pf2. And at pf2 I have all my website with html. php, css folders and so on.
Now I have 2 .htaccess files. At pf2 folder and at public_html folder

Comment: @nanmaniac, ok, so first htsccess filr in pubic folder what does it contains?

Comment: Both files are the same. Both contain what I typed in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231137/discussion-between-nanmaniac-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @nanmaniac, please place your htaccess file one level above example.com folder and then try it out?

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not get it... Why do I need 2 .htaccess? I do not understand where I should place them. I'd love an explanation or a link where some kind of tutorial

Comment: @nanmaniac, yes sure I will try to add everything for time being focusing on fixing your issue. Have only 1 htaccess, place it besides example.com folder(not inside it) let me know how it goes once we fix it I will add detailed explanation cheers

Comment: Ok, I feel super grateful with your commands. I'cve deleted all htacces and left just one in the same folder where folderexample.com is. Actually, we started there. And it works ok when you go to files that are within pf2 folder URL (example.com/index.php), but it does not work (404) when your url points to a pf2 subfolder (example.com/tree/index.php)

Comment: @nanmaniac, lets say here is your path `/singh/example.com`, then make sure htaccess file is in `singh` folder also I am considering that you are hitting link like: `http://example.com:80/` in your browser?

Comment: `/public_html/.htaccess` or `/public_html/pf2easy.com/.htaccess`  ? And i go to http://example.com (it works so far) or http://example.com/tree (it does not)

Comment: @nanmaniac, ok cool if example.com is working. What you want to see when you hit example.com/tree? Is that directory present in server?

Comment: `exaple.com` is pointing to pf2 folder (where `index.php` is placed) and `tree` is a folder within pf2 folder. I'd love to see that `https://exaple.com/tree` points to `pf2/tree`

Comment: @nanmaniac,oh ok sure got it, I have changed the rules now. Could you please use my updated rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: ouch: `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: @nanmaniac, sorry there was a typo(late night here ☺️) I have fixed it please check them now updated rules and try once. Make sure to near your browser cache before testing them. Let me know how it goes cheers

Comment: I have done it and it keeps telling me the same error

Comment: @nanmaniac,  Ok I have done changes now. Could you please check it once and let me know how it goes? Sorry it's late night here and I had written it in mobile, should be good now, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @nanmaniac, very happy to hear that, glad to help you cheers and happy learning

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

Means "if HTTPS is not switched on". In other words "only run the rule if connecting over plain "http://".

But your example shows you trying to access an "https://" URL.

You probably just don't need that condition, but if you were trying to say "if HTTPS **is** switched on", you need `=` not `!=`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
```

Comment: that's ok. Now it works but only for files that are within folder inter/pf2/ If I try to go a subfolder fo that folder it does not work. Like: https://example.com/tree gives me 404 error

Comment: Yes, because you've only matched one URL.